# Centos iptables shows rules but no service is installed

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

I realized `iptables --list` is showing rules in a CentOS server, but systemctl status/start/stop iptables says that there's no service installed.

`firewall-cmd` is disabled but I can't still telnet open ports from outside the server.

I want to know how can I temporary disable the iptables rules without deleting them since it seems there is no iptables service associated.

Thank you

Comment: do you mean firewalld ? firewall-cmd is the front end cli

Comment: firewalld is disabled, however iptables rules are taking effect (I flushed them temporary and the ports become open to outside).

Comment: Which version of Centos ?

Comment: CentOS 7.7.1908

Comment: Install the iptables-services rpm and youll be able to control it with systemd (systemctl)

Comment: Thank you, but my real question is why is iptables enabled if I didn't enable it (and I didn't create those rules) I don't want iptables so my solution will be delete the rules instead. And if is it needed to have a service to get it working since can't understand how is working know without the service.

Comment: Without knowing what else you have on the system it would be hard to tell, for example Docker relies heavily on iptables to do its network routing.

Comment: We have a Hortonworks Hadoop cluster, this is one of the nodes. We don't have docker installed on this node, we have it on other nodes and we have iptables rules there). But in this host and others on the cluster we don't have any firewall enabled. Thank you anyway ;)